# Tabular in middle of the document when I try to add table tag

Tags: tables, tabularx

Hello I have a table that takes an entire page for itself whenever I try to add this :

```
\begin{table}[H]
...
\end{table}
```

I wrapped this tabular in that table just to add caption :

```
\begin{tabular}{ | p{6em} | p{9cm} | m{3cm} | } 
\hline
 Marque & ASUS \\ 
 \hline
 Système d'éxploitation &  Windows 10 64 Bit \\
 \hline
 Processeur & Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz \\
 \hline
 RAM & 8GO \\
 \hline
 Carte graphique & Nvidia GeForce GTX 950 M \\
 \hline
 Disque dur & 500 GO \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

And it's taking an entire page and skipping everything else. How to fix this please ?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Take a look at the `caption` package and its use of the command `\captionof`.

Comment: don't use `[H]` then the table can float to a better position eg top of next page